# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: atob. Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication()

Tags: javascript, react-native, web3js

Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.

The Code that throws error:

```
//getBalance.js

import contractAbi from "@app/utils/contractAbi";
import Web3 from "web3";

export const getBalance = async (wallet) => {

    const contractAddress = "0x...";
    const jnxWallet = wallet;
    const provider = "https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545";

    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
    const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(jnxWallet).call();

    return Promise.resolve(balance / 1000000000000000000);
};
```

Used as:

```
//home.js

import { getBalance } from "@app/utils/getBalance";

useEffect(() => {
    const myBalance = getBalance("0x...");
    console.log(myBalance);
}, []);
```

What I tried:

```
//App.js
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64';

if (!global.btoa) { global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this error?

Comment: @chackerian I placed the polyfill in a separate file at the root and imported it into App.js. Additionally, I reinstalled node_modules.

Comment: What is the polyfill contents?

Comment: @chackerian import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'; if (!global.btoa) { global.btoa = encode } if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }